# Mod Rewrite for cgi-bin

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cgi

So i want to rewrite the following url structure

```
    mysite.com/cgi-bin/shop/shop.cgi/
```

to

```
    mysite.com/+
```

I have this as a rule and it works, but it doesn't force the url to print in the browser when you still point to the old url.  So I have duplicate content.  I've tried adding [R=302] to it and it doesn't work.  [R=302] makes it print the original old url structure (/cgi-bin/shop/shop.cgi/%).  Any ideas?

```
    RewriteRule ^\+([^*]+)/?$ /cgi-bin/shop/shop.cgi/$1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You've got the rewrite rule twisted around.

```
RewriteRule ^\+([^*]+)/?$ /cgi-bin/shop/shop.cgi/$1
```

means that when the client browses to the page mysite.com/+, your server will act as though they had written `mysite.com/cgi-bin/shop/shop.cgi/` instead.

If you want a rewrite to work in the opposite direction, you would need to swap the expression and the target around, like so:

```
RewriteRule /cgi-bin/shop/shop.cgi/(.*) /\+$1 [L,R]
```

This means that if the client browses to `mysite.com/cgi-bin/shop/shop.cgi/FOO`, they will get a redirect to `mysite.com/+FOO`

Please note that it is not a good idea to use both the current rule and this one at the same time, since you risk causing an infinite loop, at least if you're using redirection, since the redirect will cause a new request that will again be parsed by the redirect rules.

Comment: Hmmm, that's not working.  I tested on it's own and it's not doing anything.  Any ideas?

Comment: Turn on logging for rewrites. How to do that depends on which version of apache you're running, see docs.apache.com for information.